# How can I hide duplicates from my select query , I dont want the names and Id to show more than one time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables "punetoret" and "pagat2" I want to show the Id and Name just one time no duplicates this query is showing me a table like this

```
Id Name PagaBruto
1  asd   220
1  asd   1350
2  asd2  85
2  asd2  1350
```

How can I hide duplicates :\ ?

here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       p.Id,
       p.Name, pg.PagaBruto
FROM punetoret  p
     left join pagat2 pg ON p.Id = pg.Name_Id
GROUP BY p.Id,
         p.Name,
         pg.PagaBruto
```

[image]

Comment: So, for your sample data, what *do* you want to show? The value of your 3rd column differs, so should the value for `1` be `220`, or `1350` or something *else(?

Comment: Also that query has a `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` and no aggregation; so that is quite the confused logic you have there. If you're using a `GROUP BY` then you would normally have some form of aggregation, and if you're using aggregation then you shouldn't have any "duplicate" rows, as the `GROUP BY` (provided it's correct) will put the data into distinct groups.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `SELECT DISTINCT` is redundant with `GROUP BY`.

Second, if this query

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Name, pg.PagaBruto
FROM punetoret p LEFT JOIN
     pagat2 pg
     ON p.Id = pg.Name_Id
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Name, pg.PagaBruto
```

is returning the results you specify, then there is a difference in one of the column that you cannot see.  You don't provide enough information determine what it is.

I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT p.Id, MAX(p.Name) as p.Name, MAX(pg.PagaBruto) as PagaBruto
FROM punetoret p LEFT JOIN
     pagat2 pg
     ON p.Id = pg.Name_Id
GROUP BY p.Id;
```

What is the ultimate cause?  That depends on data types.  I am guessing that `Name` is okay because it is from the same table as `id` -- and I'm guessing `id` is unique.  However, strings on different rows can have different hidden characters (such as leading spaces) that are hard to spot.

Integers and numerics are usually fine, but floating point numbers can look the same but be different.

Comment: this code is showing me the same duplicate data :'( its not working , I want just Id and names to not duplicate the other values are ok , please help me I'm trying this for two days and I didn't find the solution , ps GROUP BY its not working with one column value I need to do GROUP BY p.Id,p.Name,pg.PagaBruto ..

Comment: @Tinn . . . I fixed the `GROUP BY` in the second query, so it should do what you want.

Comment: GROUP BY its not working with one column value I need to do GROUP BY p.Id,p.Name,pg.PagaBruto

Comment: your code is working just in MySql not in SQL server  :\

Comment: @Tinn . . . Both queries should work in any database (assuming you have reasonable types for your columns).

Comment: Column 'punetoret.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. That code is giving me this error for every column that i didn't include in Group By :\

Comment: @Tinn . . . It is the argument to `MAX()`.  That error should not occur.